# How to use @nuxtjs/fontawesome icons in buefy?

Tags: nuxt.js, font-awesome, buefy

- I am using [@nuxtjs/fontawesome](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nuxtjs/fontawesome) icons in my nuxt ssr project
- When used inside a [Buefy input](https://buefy.org/documentation/input), these icons dont render
- How do I make these work together

[CODESANDBOX illustrating my problem](https://codesandbox.io/s/nuxt-font-awesome-buefy-integration-t65dg?file=/pages/index.vue)

Comment: @kissu it wont render, the icon is there in html but doesnt render on the browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is a bit tricky and required some digging into several parts of the documentations + github issues. A working setup that I found is the following.

Create a Nuxt plugin with the following:

```js
export default {
  // ...

  plugins: [
    { src: '@/plugins/vue-buefy', mode: 'client' },
  ],
}
```

Then head to the Fontawesome Icons page and select `Free` + `Solid` as here: https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/icons?d=gallery&p=2&s=solid&m=free

Let's say we do choose `Angry` and `Air freshener`.
The latter is identified as `<i class="fas fa-air-freshener"></i>` (if you click on it). This will help us know the name of the icon to import.
This also gives us an insight that we need to use `fas`.

Then, the configuration is as following:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core' // import the mandatory

import {
  faAngry,
  faAirFreshener,
} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons' // import the icons that you've choosen, VScode may suggest the import for you!

import Buefy, { // import Buefy, required
  Dropdown, // import the component that you want to use
} from 'buefy'

import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome' // import the icon component for Buefy

library.add(
  faAngry,
  faAirFreshener,
) // add the icons you've selected
Vue.component('VueFontawesome', FontAwesomeIcon) // tell Vue to use the icon component

Vue.use(Dropdown) // same goes for the Dropdown
Vue.use(Buefy, {
  defaultIconComponent: 'vue-fontawesome', // the icon component that we are using
  defaultIconPack: 'fas', // the pack given by Fontawesome
})
```

This will help you achieve a dropdown or any component with icons. Which otherwise would have looked broken since Buefy expects that you provide it an icon library yourself.

This code will then work properly

```html
<b-dropdown aria-role="list">
  <template #trigger="{ active }">
    <b-button :icon-right="active ? 'angry' : 'air-freshener'" />
  </template>
</b-dropdown>
```

Closed dropdown
[image]

Opened dropdown
[image]